# I cannot add significance asterisks because it isn't recognizing my variables as plotted on the x-axis

Tags: ggplot2

```
my.labels <- c("UM\nControl","MM\nControl","UM\n+3dB","MM\n+3dB","UM\n0dB","MM\n0dB")

n1 <- ggplot(noise, aes(x=Experiment,y=Proportion))+
       geom_bar(colour="black", fill="#999999", stat = "identity") + 
       ylab("Proportion of females choosing attractive call")+ 
       coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1))+ xlab(NULL)+
       geom_hline(yintercept = 0.50, linetype="dotted")+
       scale_x_discrete(limits=c("UM Control","MM Control",
       "UM +3dB","MM +3dB","UM 0dB","MM 0dB"), 
       labels=my.labels) 

n2 <- n1 + geom_signif(comparisons=list(c("UM Control", "MM Control")), 
                       annotations="***",
                       y_position = 1.0,tip_length = 0,vjust=0.4)
```

n1 works well, but adding the ggsignif, it then gives the error message:
Error in f(...) : 
  Can only handle data with groups that are plotted on the x-axis

If I need to include any more info, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Please include result of `dput(noise)`

Comment: I am having this same problem with my dataset. my `dput(MYDATA)` is a huge list of the following form: `structure(list(COL1 = c("var1",...,"var1","var2",...,"var2","var3",...,"var3"), variable=structure(c(1L,...,1L), .Label="Val", class="factor"), value= c(1.2, ..., 3.2)), .Names= c("COL1","variable","value"), row.names = 370513:371512, class = "data.frame")`

Comment: @J.Con I have abbreviated my list with `...` due to lack of space

Comment: In the question I think the problem may be that the x-axis in the initial plot call is the `Experiment` values, whereas in the second call with `geom_signif()` the new x-axis labels are being called, which are not actually in the original `data frame`.